# Beginner unable to run pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have just begun using pygame and am struggling to get anything running at all, I have reduced my code to these few lines:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
```

but any code taken from working projects fails just as easily

Running this through shell causes it it to briefly open before crashing which from research IS normal?

But running it through the Python icon causes the prompt to open and close in an infinitesimal amount of time, I really don't know much about prompts so maybe it needs to be reconfigured or the PATH altered?

From research I've found that I'm meant to use a batch file but this just produces the error:

> Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'display'

I'm sure my problem is straightforward and repetitive but I'm struggling to work out where even to begin in looking for advice myself, any helps appreciated thanks!

Comment: i think the reason it comes up & goes away is because you dont have a main loop that does anything - at least look for a key to exit in a while True loop - look at other examples and you will see the construct in all programs

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.display` is a module on its own, so you need to import it:

```
import pygame
import pygame.display
```

If you just `import pygame`, you are importing the `pygame` package (or to be more exact, the `__init__.py` file inside that package's folder). And while some package import all their submodules in that file, it is nothing you can assume/expect all packages to do. Therefor it's better to explicitly import the modules inside the package instead of just importing the top-level package.

---

Another possibility: Is your file called `pygame.py` by any chance? If yes, either rename it or add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to the top of your file.

Comment: not true - the way he calls it as pygame.display.set_mode() is perfectly fine - most examples DO NOT import anything but pygame and perhaps constants - the import isnt the problem

Comment: My guess would also be that the file is called pygame.py. It would help if we could see the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a major corruption in your Pygame installation. Remove it, if necessary re-download, then re-install and try again.

Also make sure that you did not use any file name like "pygame.py" for your files. It would cause namespace-conflicts. So if you name your file "pygame.py" and then do "import pygame", it's basically your file being imported and I bet, you don't have a "display" class in there...

I used precisely the lines you have posted in your question and they run perfectly (Python 3.4, PyGame 1.9.2 on WinXP).

Answer (score -3):

I just use

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
```

Works fine.